# If statement that will only to execute the code if the number is not lower than it is

Tags: javascript

I have a an integer, lets say 9. I want to create a condition that will allow the user to click the button ONLY if this 9 is NOT LOWER than it is. How do I handle this.

```
if(not lower than 9){
  execute the code here....
}
```

Comment: you mean `if (a >= 9)`?

Comment: Your question is not clear!

Comment: I dont have any variable, lets say all I have is a number like 9

Comment: @kuwame and you compare it to **what**? Comparison is a binary operator and so you need two arguments to make it meaningful.

Comment: if (9 < 9) console.log("oh my God!");

Answer (score 3):

unfortunately 9 will always be 9. but if 9 is assigned to a variable, then you can do `if (variable >= 9) { .... }`

Actually, considering how weird your condition is, it will work the way you want

```
if (9) {
   // code
}
```

it's the same as `if (true) {` but there, 9 is not lower than 9, it is equal to 9, so it will enter the condition. pff. Just don't test it for 0.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that you have got the value of this integer in a variable named num, and button with id "Btn1", you can try code similar to the following:

```
if (num >= 9)
{
    $("#Btn1").removeAttr("disabled");
}
else
{
    $("#Btn1").attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

`.removeAttr("disabled")` will enable the button, and `.attr("disabled", "disabled")` will make the button disabled.

Comment: +1 I guess you're first one that catched what he did mean...

Comment: With recent versions of jQuery, the use of the `.prop()` method is preferred over `.attr()` for things like "disabled", "checked", etc. - http://api.jquery.com/prop/